# "You've really DID it" heard it in an American tv series

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

In the second episode of season 6 of the HBO series Girls, a girl is telling her grandma, "You've really did it." in a context of passing years. It's totally incorrect so please, can someone explain this to me? Why didn't she say, "You've really done it." ?

Comment: are you sure she didn’t say, “You really did it.”?

Comment: Why didn't you say "why didn't she say"?

Comment: Because she is an uneducated speaker, that's why. Let's just say it, shall we? That is what I call a "class"-based mistake". It's marked as anuneducated sociolect and that speaker would also probably say: She don't like me. [caveat: I do not give a hoot about how people speak unless they are supposed to speak a certain way. I hear CNN journalists and commentators who are INCAPALBE of using the conditional correctly: If it rainED, I would go. I hear: If it would rain, I would go. Those are the people to bash, those types of people. They are paid to know better!!]

Comment: We have no idea why she said what she said...

Comment: Basically, hickspeak.

Comment: Can you cite your research resources? Such as a wiki?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks context, and any  support in the form of links or reputable sources.

Comment: Thank You @Lambie. I tottaly get it. Its kinda like this common mistake "If i wouldve voted, I wouldve voted for...".

Comment: I'll check it @Jim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Television shows are usually comedic. Like @Lambie said,

> Because she is an uneducated speaker, that's why. [...] It's marked as an uneducated sociolect and that speaker would also probably say: She don't like me.

There are numerous times when television shows purposely have their character speak incorrect English. This is, like I said above, for comedic relief. Some people find grammatical stupidity funny.

**EDIT:**
Kind of like the new popular meme: "Cash me ousside how bow dah!"

Comment: Can somebody explain why I got downvoted, as there aren't any other answers here?

Comment: Although I also haven't voted against this answer, I'll be a little more express with my hypothesis since you have asked: I doubt there is presently enough context to answer the question definitively . Your hypothesis is one of at least several reasons the statement may have been uttered. What if this is not played off for comedy, but instead an honest, heat-of-the-moment mistake elicited by excitement for one of grandma's recent successes? I am not currently sure enough what a "passing years" context is.  We also usually expect answers to be corroborated by facts, experiences and references.

Comment: @Tonepoet The context Is in the second episode of season 6 HBO Girls

Comment: Thank You @Emereal. I tottaly get it. Its kinda like this common mistake "If i wouldve voted, I wouldve voted for...".

Comment: @Nick Now you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: @Emereal did it